# Filter by category is not working in spree sunspot search

Tags: spree, sunspot-solr

I am facing problem in spree sunspot(solr) search.

Filter by price is working file but issue in filter by category.

I am using 
rails- 4.1.6,
ruby 2.2.0,
spree_sunspot (1.3)

spree_sunspot.rb

```
string :category_names, :multiple => true do
    category = Spree::Taxon.find_by_permalink('categories')
    taxons.select{|t| t.ancestors.include?(category)}.collect{|t| t.self_and_ancestors.map(&:name)}.flatten - [category.name]
  end
```

spree_sunspot_filters.rb

```
filters.add do |f|
      f.display_name = 'Category'
      f.search_condition = :any
      f.search_param = 'category_name'
      f.values { Spree::Taxon.find_by_permalink('categories').children.map(&:name) }
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue rebuild the index page and Its working fine.

> rake sunspot:reindex